# Problem rename multiple files

Tags: rename

I try to rename those files with .txt extension using rename command:

```
rename -n 's/new//' *
```

... the idea here is to change names of files to  1 , 2 ,3 and etc; and the output is:

```
rename(new1.txt, 1.txt)
rename(new2.txt, 2.txt)
rename(new3.txt, 3.txt) ...
```

I think that the command pass ... but nothing change.
and this is permission of directory at which files are:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Jan 25 14:59  nf2020
```

Comment: Take a look at `man rename` to see what the `-n`-flag does.

Comment: `rename -n` takes no action, it simply will print the name of files to rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the synopsis in the man page states the usage is as follows:

```
rename [options] expression replacement file...
```

At least three parameters are required:

- an initial expression that is currently in place
- an target expression to what the file(s) shall be renamed
- a selection of files to apply the rename to

So try this command:

```
rename 'new' '' *.txt
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: That looks like the syntax for the `util-linux` implementation of `rename` - it looks like the OP has the (more typical for Debian/Ubuntu) Perl-based implementation. See for example [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275254/why-is-the-rename-utility-on-debian-ubuntu-different-than-the-one-on-other-distr)

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver for pointing this out. I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for the perl version of `rename`:

```
rename 's/new//' *.txt
```

Skip the `-n` if you actually want to apply the rename operations.